# Compile Valgrind for armv5

Tags: assembly, arm, valgrind, cross-compiling

everyone. I got some problems while cross compile valgrind for armv5(arm926ej-s). I can figure out some of them, but there is one I cannot solve. I will write these problems:

1. Valgrind don't support armv5 in `configure`, I instead `armv7*)` with `armv7*|arm*)` and it works well.
2. `-mcpu=cortex-a8` is not right since I have a arm926ej-s CPU. So I use this command to replace them all in Makfiles:

   > sed -i 's/-mcpu=cortex-a8/-mcpu=arm926ej-s/g' `find . -name
   >   "Makefile*"`
3. There comes the problem. `movw` and `movt` in the source code is not supported by armv5. The error message is:

> ```
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S: Assembler messages:
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:122: Error: selected processor does not support `movw r1,#47'
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:123: Error: selected processor does not support `movw r2,#0'
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:175: Error: selected processor does not support `movw   r1,#:lower16:vgPlain_stats__n_xindirs_32'
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:176: Error: selected processor does not support `movt r1,#:upper16:vgPlain_stats__n_xindirs_32'
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:183: Error: selected processor does not support `movw r1,#(((1<<15))-1)'
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:184: Error: selected processor does not support `movw r4,#:lower16:vgPlain_tt_fast'
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:187: Error: selected processor does not support `movt r4,#:upper16:vgPlain_tt_fast'
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:200: Error: selected processor does not support `movw r1,#:lower16:vgPlain_stats__n_xindir_misses_32'
> m_dispatch/dispatch-arm-linux.S:201: Error: selected processor does not support `movt r1,#:upper16:vgPlain_stats__n_xindir_misses_32'
> ```

I'm thinking of instead of `movw` and `movt` with `mov`. But I'm not familiar with assembly code. Any one could help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to cross-compiled Valgrind for this processor yet? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some patches on [bug 248998](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=248998) in the valgrind bug tracker which attempt to add support for armv5 but I have no how complete they are or how well they work.

They would probably make a good starting point for your work anyway.

Comment: I am facing the same problem using the latest version of Valgrind, is there any way to solve this yet?

Comment: @ToanTran The [patch](https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=117327) provided by Chris Paulson-Ellis seems to work.