# How to build Valgrind for ARMv5 platforms?

Tags: debugging, arm, valgrind, cross-compiling

I need to debug a multi-threaded program which keeps throwing horrible segmentation faults, and I chose **Valgrind** to do so. The problem, though, is that the code is cross-compiled and run in an ARMv5 machine. I tried to build Valgrind for that architecture, but `configure` failed because that version is not supported:

```
$ CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  ./configure --prefix=/opt/valgrind     \
  --host=armv5-none-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi  \
  --build=i386-ubuntu-linux

(...)
checking for a supported CPU... no (armv5)
configure: error: Unsupported host architecture. Sorry
```

Is there a way to solve this issue? Could it be somehow possible to compile for ARMv7 (which I read is fully supported), and use it in my platform? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853124/compile-valgrind-for-armv5), but it was asked two years ago and the answer points to a patch for older versions of Valgrind.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228339/valgrind-cross-compilation-for-armv5tel/4336133

Answer (score 5):

If you get to compile valgrind for an ARMv5 instruction set CPU you cannot run it since valgrind only runs on ARMv7 CPUs.

[Valgrind cross compilation for ARMv5tel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228339/valgrind-cross-compilation-for-armv5tel/4336133#4336133)

ARM support seems to be added since "Release 3.6.0 (21 October 2010)":

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html

But it has to run on an ARMv7 CPU even if it supports older instruction sets.

I compiled valgrind for an ARMv5 and it does not run, it throws "Illegal instruction".

https://community.nxp.com/message/863066?commentID=863066#comment-863066

Comment: It's also in the official doc: http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html `ARM/Linux: supported since ARMv7.`

Answer (score 0):

In configure file change "armv7*" to "arm", then your compilation will success.

Comment: Yes, but the resultant executable won't actually run on an armv5.